# how to create a database diagram in sybase

Tags: database, sybase, database-diagramming

I am new to sybase. IS there a way to create a database diagram as in SQLServer Management Studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerDesigner is sold by Sybase, with integration **to** (create objects in a target database) and **from** (reverse-engineer a database) Sybase ASE.

However it is immature and clunky.  Originally built for Oracle, integrated to the lowest levels of detail, and not yet completely to that point with Sybase.

The best tool for modelling databases is **ERwin**.  It happens to have better integration with Sybase, as well as a slew of features for enterprise modelling that PowerDesigner does not have.  It is very mature, and implements the Relational Modelling Standard (IDEF1X).

Both are expensive.  But there are other options:

- if all you need is a diagramming tool, anything will do (OmniGraffle; ABCFlowCharter; VS).  Then do your database administration in SybaseCentral (free from Sybase) or DBArtisan or various other offerings.
- You can also model in SQLServer Management Studio; produce a DDL file; then import that into Sybase.  That requires resolving the difference between Sybase and MS SQL syntax.  No big deal if you are not specifying low level (physical) elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best tool is Sybase PowerDesigner (Database Architect edition). 
As far as I remember one license is included in ASE.